# HTML <object> Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to start this question by saying that I'm very new to HTML and don't have any formal experience. My goal is to add a snippet of HTML code containing an interactive figure into **another** HTML document. I have figured out how to do this by using the `<object> Tag`. The only problem I'm facing is that `data=` field needs a **URL** to a separate file. I can't have a two HTML files, as I need to give my client a **single** HTML. Is there a way to create a new `string` containing the HTML code of the interactive figure -- then pass it to the `data=` field? Or something similar?

`<object align="center" style="width:30%;height:500px" data="/Users/Desktop/plotly_test2.html"></object>`

To reiterate: I was able to use `<object> Tag` to load the interactive figures into my HTML; however, I am looking for a way to supply the `data=` field with a `string` of the HTML, rather than a path to an HTML file.

`<object align="center" style="width:30%;height:500px" data="/Users/Desktop/plotly_test2.html"></object>`

Comment: Why not use a plain div instead of the object tag, and within it paste the HTML markup from the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by encoding the inner HTML using the URL data scheme.

This is most often [done with small images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html).

The URL becomes something like so:

```
... data="data:<HTML-base64-encoded>" ...
```

Of course, the prohibits easy editing, although you can write a script to convert your two HTML documents into one, automatically.

---

As a side note, in most cases people use `<iframe ...>` to include another HTML page, rather than `<object ...>`.

Comment: Hi Alexis! I tried converting my interative HTML code to base 64 and included it into data="data:<my-base-64-encoded-html-code>"; however, my figure isn't present when loading the HTML. The figure is only present when I actually include the path to the HTML file itself.

Comment: @calin20796 Hmmm... if you mean that the base64 HTML code includes an `<img ...>` then that image many also need to be base64 within that HTML. I haven't used that before, so I don't know whether it would work... Logically, it should since the browser will first parse the `<object ...>` and then find the `<img ...>` and parse that accordingly.

Comment: Fixed it with <p align="center"><iframe style="width:30%;height:500px"; src="data:text/html;base64,"; frameBorder="0"></iframe></p>

Thanks for the tip about iframe